# How to select HTML with jQuery when it has no unique identifying attributes but has an HTML comment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I am writing a custom script for a forum I frequently visit. It is designed to remove signatures from the board when I view it because they are distracting and annoying and they have no way to disable them in the options.

Anyway, I can run custom scripts using a helpful Chrome extension. I am able to modify any portions of the page where HTML nodes have classes, IDs, or even attributes with a little bit of unique information, but I can't seem to figure out how to select and remove the following HTML with jQuery.

```
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <!--Signature-->
            <div class="resultText">
                <!-- sig -->
                    <div>Signature text</div>
                <!-- / sig -->

            </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

If there was a way I could grab the parent of `<!--Signature-->` that would be perfect but I'm not sure that's even possible.

There is one class `resultText` but that class is used wherever there is text entered by the user, not just in the signature. So I can't grab onto that.

Comment: Why don't you just add some info (id, class, whatever) to make this work?  Using comments is a terrible idea even if it is possible.

Comment: Even if this was possible, it would be extremely slow. I would recommend adding some identity to the elements themselves. i.e. id, class data-

Comment: @all - this isn't his site so he doesn't have control over the content. That's why he can't add in an identifier.

Comment: @EdS. It's not my site as mrtsherman said. It's a Chrome mod running when I visit the site. All I can do is tweak the existing contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.contents()` to get all the child nodes of an element: http://api.jquery.com/contents

From the docs:

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   including text and comment nodes.

```
$('tr').each(function (index, obj) {
    $(this).children('td').contents();//this selects all the nodes in each TD element in the table, including comment nodes
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NLhz9/1/

Comment: How might I use this to locate the node containing the `<!--Signature-->` comment?

Comment: @AlexFord When you select an element's children with `.contents()` you can iterate through the jQuery collection and look at the `nodeType` and `nodeValue` properties to determine what node you are working with. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NLhz9/1/

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted. Here is my final usage of your code http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/NLhz9/2/

Comment: @AlexFord Looks good! If you have multiple `<td>` elements with the `signature` comment, you can remove the `break` in the `for` loop and put `$(tmp[i]).parent().remove();` right in the `for` loop's `if/then` statement.

Answer (score 5):

Even if the `resultText` class is used elsewhere, I'd still recommend using a class selector as a starting point, otherwise you will be looking for comment nodes in the entire document.

From the matched elements, you can get their parents' [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to isolate the comment nodes (their [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) property is equal to `8`) and compare the value of these nodes to your `Signature` string:

```
$(".resultText").parent().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var signature = $this.contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 8 && this.nodeValue == "Signature";
    });
    if (signature.length) {
        // Signature found, $this is the <td> element.
        $this.closest("tr").remove();  // For example.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the script is basically just for you, use xpath to find the comments.

Try something like this:

```
var comment, comments = document.evaluate('//comment()', document);
while ((comment=comments.iterateNext())) {
  if (comment.data=='Signature') { // found one
    comment.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(comment.parentNode);
  }
}
```